# Белый экран при запуске приложения на Ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic

При запуске приложения на Ionic после сплеш-скрина отображается просто белый экран. При тестах на ПК в браузере та же проблема, но она решается обновлением страницы, в то время как с реального устройства невозможно обновить страницу. В чём может быть проблема? Может быть кто то сталкивался?

Comment: Так и надо решить проблему белого экрана в браузере, а не решать обновлением страницы.

Answer (score 0):

Сделал, небольшое тестовое приложение..такая же ерунда. Причем на телефоне с Android 4.2 - белый экран. На телефоне с Android 6.0 - все отлично работает. Не пойму в чем причина, хотя приложение строилось для смартфона от 4 версии и выше..

Comment: Кажется я тогда всё таки решил эту проблему, но не помню точно что же там случилось. Вроде бы был какой то баг со стандартными классами ionic. В них используется css-свойство "transform" и он по разному отрабатывает в старых и новых браузерах на андроид. Попробуйте через браузер отдебажить. Поубирать это свойство у главных блоков.

Comment: Вы используете в своем проекте <ion-slide-box>? Я испытываю проблемы с скроллингом страницы при наличии этого слайдера на странице.